# Add block in layout XML only for one store view

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, blocks, xml, layout-update

I have a Magento 2.1.x installation with two store views.
I would like to show a particular block in the footer only for one store view.

In Magento 1.9.x I would have done it in this way:

```
<STORE_storecode>
    <reference name="lorem_ipsum">
        <block type="..." />
    </reference>
</STORE_storecode>
```

How can I achieve that in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can do that in Magento 2, the cleanest way I can think of would be to :

1. Create a new theme that uses your current theme as a parent
2. Set your second store to use the new theme
3. Extend the layout XML in your new theme with your change

You'll end up with the same effect, although it is more work than the method you mentioned for Magento 1.

Comment: Creating additional theme which results in greater compilation time in production mode while deploying version is a very bad idea.

Comment: What is so bad with an additional x seconds of deployment?

Comment: When time means money and every second of maintenance generates debt,  where bad solutions like your stacks - it can lead to many problems. It doesn't matter in small scale (however bad solution is a bad solution). Also, depending o theme it can be far more than seconds plus there are still magento bugs eg. with generating translations which may result in repeated deployment.  And finally,  i will not understand why I would like to create additional theme for something that can be done with one if?

Comment: If I was aware of that method I would have added it, but I wasn't aware hence I say "the cleanest way I can think of"  and not "the cleanest way is".

Comment: I did not meant to be harsh, I do not fully capture semantic of English words. I just disagree with your solution and perceive it as an expensive one. That is all. I hope that my explanation make sens.

Comment: It's no problem, you have a very good point and your answer sounds like the better option. I'm a front-end developer so I don't work with deployments too much hence my answer isn't great. It's the joys of stack exchange, you get a wide variety of answers.

Comment: Also why is this feature is not present in M2?

Comment: The feature is there in the way that you can create a new theme and apply that to a certain store view, which makes perfect sense to me. For example if you have a Spanish and an English store view you may want to apply certain styling differences to each store view which you would create a new theme for. 

If they added the ability to change Layout XML based on store views it makes different themes redundant, and if people did this you'd likely end up with one huge theme rather than several smaller themes.

Comment: Although you can technically do this in the admin, you can add layout XML to certain categories/pages on certain store views.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in layout xml which is not possible in M2 you can either override/plugin toHtml method in block and implement required logic or add such a logic as separate method in block to call in if/else structure inside of phtml file.

Comment: Hm, how exactly can you override the block class of an existing block?